# ignite TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder vs TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder

Tags: ignite

`TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder` and `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder` are used to connect with the `gird` **BUT** i want to understand the `difference` between them and when do i need to use each one ?

What is the Multicast Group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder:** It works with pre-configured list of IP addresses specified via setAddresses(Collection) method. By default, this IP finder is not shared(other nodes will not able to find it dynamically).

It also let the node not to wait while other nodes join the cluster but rather become the first cluster node and operate normally.

**TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder:** If you want the nodes from different clusters are able to look for each other using multicast protocol then use TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder and set unique multicastGroup(it's group address where all nodes connect).

> In one line it is "Static" vs "Dynamic" node finding.

Hope this answer will help you.